# How can I see, all my chatrooms in one CollectionViewController?

Tags: swift, firebase

So I tried to make all chatrooms into one CollectionViewController but I can only see one and in that one I can't see the image and the label I named the chatroom. All I see is a white picture and the original label. My code:

```
func CreateNewRoom(user: User, caption: String, data: NSData) {
    let filePath = "\(user.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))"
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error uploading: \(error as NSError)")
            return
        }
        let chatRef = self.storageRef.child("images/chat.jpg")

        chatRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if error != nil {

            } else {

            }
        }
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
            idRoom.setValue(["caption": caption, "thumbnailUrlFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metadata!.path!).description, "fileUrl": self.fileUrl])
        }
    }
}
func fetchDataFromServer(callback: @escaping (Room) -> ()) {
    DataService.dataService.ROOM_REF.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        print("FOUND ROOM "+snapshot.key)

        let room = Room(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        callback(room)
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, you are uploading a file in the format `\(user.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)).jpg` and then trying to download one called images/chat.jpg?, but not doing anything with the downloadURL anyway. so I'm not suprised you aren't getting the image displaying. you need to break this down into individual issues. don't try and fix everything at once. I would use local/fake/temporary data to get the cell displaying correctly and loading the images, then work on pulling/pushing data from firebase. and your code doesn't even show anything to do with a collectionView

Comment: @Scriptable yea I agree my code is pretty bad. Is there anywhere a guide where I can startover and learn building rooms from scratch?

Comment: loads on Google... go nuts: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can only see one chat room is because you're calling `observeSingleEventv`, which stop listening after the first child node. To get all child nodes from `ROOM_REF`, use `observe`.

So:

```
func fetchDataFromServer(callback: @escaping (Room) -> ()) {
    DataService.dataService.ROOM_REF.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        print("FOUND ROOM "+snapshot.key)

        let room = Room(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        callback(room)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! now I can see all the chatrooms. Do you know how to see the image and room name instead of blank and label?